# Calling two procedures VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

```
Public Shared Function Save() As Boolean
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
        With cmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "Insert_Detail"
            .CommandTimeout = 100
            .Connection = Connection.GetConnection
            .Transaction = Connection.GetConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)

            .Parameters.Add("@detailId", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            .Parameters.Add("@saleId", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Sale.SaleId
            .Parameters.Add("@foodId", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = Food.FoodId
            .Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Price
            .Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = Qty
            .Parameters.Add("@discount", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = Food.Discount

            Try
                .ExecuteNonQuery()

                Dim _detailId As Long = .Parameters("@detailId").Value

                DetailSale.DetailId = _detailId
                DetailRemark.Save()

                .Transaction.Commit()
                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                .Transaction.Rollback()
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                Return False
            End Try
        End With
    End Using
End Function

Public Shared Function Save() As Boolean
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
        With cmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "Insert_Detail_Remark"
            .CommandTimeout = 100
            .Connection = Connection.GetConnection

            .Parameters.Add("@detailId", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = DetailSale.DetailId
            .Parameters.Add("@remarkIdAsString", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = RemarkIdAsString
            .Parameters.Add("@priceAsString", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = PriceAsString

            Try
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                Return False
            End Try
        End With
    End Using
End Function
```

I have these two functions to call different procedure. when I run it, it can work only procedure. function  DetailRemark.Save() it is not working. How can I do?

Comment: Pass as parameter to the DetailRemark the connection object and perform with that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do these functions exist in same class? If so you cannot have multiple functions with same signature.

Secondly, it's better to create separate functions (with different names) as they are not related.

Comment: These two functions are not in the same class. But I use beginTran is not yet commit. So when I execute other procedure, it raises error.